# Using Windows 7 after Ubuntu 12.1 restarts Windows and signs me into a guest account

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows

I have very little experience with Ubuntu, and I just spent all weekend trying it out and installing it finally on my laptop. After I installed it and ran it for awhile because I couldn't find my old files. So I restarted the computer in Windows and it acted as if I had just started Windows 7 for the first time.

All of my programs were gone from the desktop, it reset the toolbar at the bottom and I lost my theme. It then tells me I'm on a guest account and that all of my information will be lost when I turn it off. All of my data was on the hard drive though, so nothing was lost. Is there a way I can keep my user data on Windows 7 as well as Ubuntu? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 and Ubuntu are separate one has nothing to do with the other. I am not sure why you are being logged in to a guest account, but rest assured, You won't hurt your Ubuntu install by rebooting windows.